# react-native ScrollView display an absolute item outside of the ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

Hi I have tooltip buttons in my TextInput when user press open a tooltip and I'm taking TextInput values from an array because of that I'm using ScrollView or FlatList.

My problem is that the tooltip of the TOP TextInput is not all visible. As you see in the below tooltip of StoreKey stays outside of ScrollView(PINK).

Is there any way to show it outside of the ScrollView ?

Note: I can use also FlatList.

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this? I would like to do something similar.